# I'm receiving Windows Update error 8024402f after changing update to include MS office

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, updates

Brand new Dell desktop with Windows 7 Ultimate.

Windows Update works fine until I add MS office 2007 and then change Windows update to "Get updates for other Microsoft products.  Then the error starts to appear.

When I change it back to update only windows, the error goes away.

Answer (score 1):

just ran into this odd issue. This is what worked for me:

**Step 1: Change Windows Updates Settings**
Right click on the Start button (bottom-left) and select Control Panel. Or, if you prefer the gesture approach, go to the bottom-right corner and then click on Settings -> Control Panel.

Click on Windows Update and then, in the left column, select Change settings.

**Step 2: Deactivate everything**
Change Windows Updates settings to “Never Check for Updates“. Also make sure to turn off the “Give me recommended updates the same way I receive important updates” and the “Give me updates for other Microsoft products when I update Windows” options by remove the checkmark on both. Don’t worry, you’ll be able to set them back on in a while.

**Step 3: Perform a manual Update**
Select the “Check for updates” and perform a Windows Update manually.

**Step 4: Put everything back on**
As soon as the update finishes, restart the system (if needed), then open Control Panel > Windows Update again and reactivate all the options you previously had – and/or you want to activate. They should work as expected from now on: if not, you’ll have to repeat these 4 steps again until it will eventually fix.

I've also tried to explain the whole process in the following post:
http://www.ryadel.com/2015/07/18/windows-8-1-how-to-fix-windows-update-error-8024402f/