# How to include Office 2003 in Windows Automatic Updates

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, windows-update

I've got a few new PC's with Windows 7 to roll-out for our office, but before I complete one and create an image to use for the others, I want to get Office 2003 fully up-to-date.

I can't seem to find anywhere that allows me to include Office updates in the Windows Automatic Updates...

When I searched on the web for this, I found an article that refers to Vista (https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mu/2009/03/20/enabling-microsoft-update-to-keep-office-2003-office-xp-and-other-microsoft-products-secure-and-up-to-date/).  However, whenever I've used the link in "Step 1" on previous computers, it includes Office in the updates, but then the Windows update has an error `8024402F Windows Update encountered an unknown error` which is a real pain to fix.

[image]

Can anyone help?

***EDIT:***
Please ignore that this is in an office/corporate environment.  I am aware of WSUS and GPO's but don't wish to use them here.
I have installed the latest Office 2003 service pack (SP3) after the install and activation of Office.

Comment: How does your office install updates.  By downloading them from Microsoft or do you have your own WSUS server?

Comment: no WSUS.  Not even GPO.
Just using automatic updates every Monday at 1pm.
That's sort of irrelevant to my question though.  I want to know how I can successfully include Office in the Automatic Updates (regardless of whether it's standalone or on a corporate network)

Comment: Oh, you mean like this - [link](http://i.imgur.com/AVF4e16.png) ???
Please tell me where at that location I can include Office in the updates...
Trust me - if it was that simple, I wouldn't be asking this question.  And yes, WSUS is irrelevant in this topic.  I've done more research than you're assuming.  I don't have a WSUS server in this office, & don't want to set one up for it at the moment.  In fact - ignore that my question ever includes reference to an office or corporate environment or roll-outs.  I just want to know how to include MS Office in the updates in a way that doesn't error.

Comment: SP3 was the first thing I did after installing and activating Office 2k3.

Comment: Have you installed `Microsoft Update`?  You get get a valid link for Windows 7 by clicking `Get Updates for more Products` based on the screenshot you posted you don't have it installed.  **If you did then the screenshot you posted would look different.**

Comment: here is someone with the same issue for Office 2007: http://superuser.com/questions/684038/im-receiving-windows-update-error-8024402f-after-changing-update-to-include-ms Phone the MS support, you should get free support for Update issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to configure that unless you install a program Microsoft considers important enough for ***Microsoft Updates***. Microsoft Office 2003 must not have made the cut.

Go download and install [Silverlight](https://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/), being sure to activate ***Microsoft Updates*** as you do.

Now go and run that "Windows Updates" that comes with Windows 7. It will now include Office 2003.

Voila.

Comment: thanks!  (we moved away from Office 2003 back in April, but this is handy to know if we need to setup a PC for legacy apps)